# Error Trying to get property 'id' of non-object with data from the API using cURL from ixudra/cURL

Tags: laravel, curl, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to display data from the API using the libarary of ixudra / curl,
when I try dd he gets the data, but when I try to show in the view there is an error Trying to get property 'id' of non-object this my view code

```
@foreach($outputData as $data)
  {{$data->id}}
@endforeach
```

**Controller:**

```
$response = Curl::to('127.0.0.1/user/data')->get();
$data = json_decode($response, true);    
$outputData = $data["data"];        
return view('feature/vendor',compact('outputData'));
```

**Output:**

```
$outputData[1];

//On expanding

array:6 [▼
  "id" => 3
  "post_id" => 115
  "status" => "active"
  "updated_at" => "2019-11-15 12:57:41"
  "created_at" => "2019-11-15 12:57:41"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not object , it is array , so make a change like this

```
@foreach($outputData as $data)
    {{$data['id']}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: what if I want to release the data in view ?

Comment: What do you mean I quiet confuse what data do you want to release? You already output this right?